# How to make reset input fileds after click submit in ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, mobile, ionic3, angular5, reset

I waste much time in solving this problem I want when i submit the form the input fields will clear  can some  help me with this  or can show links about it

thanks guys...

Comment: Can you provide your code? Which fields are you trying to clear?

Answer (score 1):

Have you figure this out? if not you can check this link [submitting-and-resetting](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/forms/submitting-and-resetting/)

> In a model-driven form to reset the form we just need to call the function reset() on our myform model.
>
> For our sample form let’s reset the form in the onSubmit() function,
>   like so:

```
onSubmit() {   
  if (this.myform.valid) {
     console.log("Form Submitted!");
     this.myform.reset();   
  } 
}
```

> The form now resets, all the input fields go back to their initial state and any valid, touched or dirty properties are also reset to their starting values.

You can try my example at Tab2 page [example](https://ionic-v4-angular-tabs-odamse.stackblitz.io)